# ElasticSearch 5 - Migrating "missing" filter

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch 1 and 2.x there was a "missing" filter which was used in the app we're currently migrating to 5.

The "missing" filter was used to create a selection like this:
 Return all results where price is missing or price > 100.

In ES5, the missing filter does not exist anymore and the docs say it can be replaced with a combination of "must_not" and "exists", but in my case, I'm writing an "or" query and there is no "should_not" clause.

Excerpt from the docs at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html:

> missing query has been removed because it can be advantageously replaced by an exists query inside a must_not clause as follows:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "user"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would you go about migrating this in ES5?

Thanks!

UPDATE: This is the PHP / Elastica code that is used to build the query. Unfortunatly I don't have the query in JSON, as the app doesn't run at this time. The idea is simple though: I want all results where the "price" is missing or greater than 100.

```
$and = new \Elastica\Filter\BoolFilter();
$and->addMust(new \Elastica\Filter\Term(array('highlights_ids' => $highlight->getId())));

$or = new \Elastica\Filter\BoolOr();
$or->addFilter(new \Elastica\Filter\Missing('price')); // if price is missing => show always
$or->addFilter(new \Elastica\Filter\Range("price", array('from' => $minPrice)));
$and->addMust($or);

$filter = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery(null, $and);
$query = new \Elastica\Query($filter);

$query->setFields(array()); // No fields, we get them from the db
$query->setSize($max);

$result = $this->tripProvider->search($query);
```

Comment: Can you share the query which are you using currently and want to migrate in 5.

Comment: I don't have the query in JSON (the app is broken atm), but I added the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `should` query will do the needful

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                 "exists": {
                    "field": "price"
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        {
            "range": {
               "price": {
                  "from": 100
               }
            }
        }
     ]
    }
   }
}
```